# Passing a Python List to GeocodeAddresses

Tags: arcpy, geocoding, list

Currently I have a list of locations, like the following:

```
locations = ["Atlanta, GA", "Rochester, NY", "Paris, France"]
```

I would like to geocode these locations using `arcpy.geocoding.GeocodeAddresses`.

This function takes in a table as the first parameter.  Is there a way for me to use the Python list I have instead of making an extraneous file? Or is the only way to write the list I have into a file?

Comment: have you tried placing your list in the first parameter? Whats the error message

Comment: @Geo.Dude I have! It's very generic: `RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool`

Comment: the document I provided below says its a input table, so it appears you must provide a table. you can add the code snippet create a table (csv) with your list then use that table for the geocoder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export your python list to csv and then use that file as your input table

```
import csv

with open(..., 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(mylist)
```

Here is the documentation for that function
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002600000006000000.htm

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to write an extraneous CSV file, but it seems that isn't possible.  Thanks!